# Can't open a file with a Japanese filename in Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

Why doesn't this work in the Python interpreter? I am running the Python 2.7 version of python.exe on Windows 7. My locale is en_GB.

```
open(u'黒色.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: u'??.txt'
```

The file does exist, and is readable.

And if I try

```
name = u'黒色.txt'
name
```

the interpreter shows

```
u'??.txt'
```

Additional:

Okay, I was trying to simplify my problem for the purposes of this forum. Originally the filename was arriving in a cgi script from a web page with a file picker. The idea was to let the web page user upload files to a server:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileItems = form['attachment[]']

for fileItem in fileItems:
    if fileItem.file:
        fileName = os.path.split(fileItem.filename)[1]

        f = open(fileName, 'wb')
        while True:
            chunk = fileItem.file.read(100000)
            if not chunk: 
                break
            f.write(chunk)
        f.close()
```

but the files created at the server side had corrupted names. I started investigating this in the Python interpreter, reproduced the problem (so I thought), and that is what I put into my original question. However, I think now that I managed to create a separate problem.

Thanks to the answers below, I fixed the cgi script by making sure the file name is treated as unicode:

```
fileName = unicode(os.path.split(fileItem.filename)[1])
```

I never got my example in the interpreter to work. I suspect that is because my PC has the wrong locale for this.

Comment: What interpreter are you using?  Running from a script where you can control the encodings may help.

Comment: I'm running python.exe, but the interpreter isn't really the issue; I need to be able to do this inside a script as well.

Comment: My answer shows how to do it.  You have to provide more info to figure out how you got the result you did.  Provide a reproducible use case.

Comment: Where does the filename come from? Do you have a **literal** string in your Python code: `u'黒色.txt'`? What is `print os.listdir(u'.')`? Namely, does `u'黒色.txt' in os.listdir(u'.')` return `True`?

Comment: The updated part after *"Additional"* is a different question: while "simplifying" you've lost the initial issue and introduced another one. Don't use `unicode()` on a bytes object, call `.decode('ascii', 'strict')` instead, to make it clear what's happening (What `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns in the server?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example script that reads and writes the file.  You can use any encoding for the source file that supports the characters you are writing but make sure the `#coding` line matches.  You can use any encoding for the data file as long as the `encoding` parameter matches.

```
#coding:utf8
import io
with io.open(u'黒色.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(u'黒色.txt content')

with io.open(u'黒色.txt',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Output:

```
黒色.txt content
```

Note the `print` will only work if the terminal running the script supports Japanese; otherwise, you'll likely get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.  I am on Windows and use an IDE that supports UTF-8 output, since the Windows console uses a legacy US-OEM encoding that doesn't support Japanese.

Comment: That the script could be entered at all means the terminal probably supports Japanese, unless it's being run from a file that was saved in another editor.

Comment: @MarkRansom, in Linux maybe, not Windows, unless the OP is running on a Japanese variant.  More likely using a GUI editor, but getting that result from attempting to run at the command prompt in Windows.  It looks like it's gone through a `mbcs` translation.  If only the OP wrote a small, reproducible example... :)

Comment: @CharlesAnderson, How did you try it?  Show us how to reproduce the error message.  Are you running at the console?  How did you determine your locale?  If running at the console, what does `chcp` return?  Did you use a script saved in UTF-8 and the exact code above?

Answer (score 0):

Run IDLE if you want to work with Unicode strings interactively in Python. Then inputting or printing any characters will just work.